# When does the while loop stop when given only a variable

Tags: c

```
int gcd(int x, int y) {
    int t;
    while (y) {
        t = x;
        x = y;
        y = t % y;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Does it stop when y = 0? I thought the loop stops when y isn't defined.

Comment: Zero = logical-false (non-zero = logical-true);

Comment: There's no such thing as _isn't defined_ in C, maybe you're thinking of Javascript.

Comment: how could you made a defined variable undefined?

Comment: Technically, they loop while the condition inside of parenthesis evaluates to true. In the case of an int, 0 is treated as a false condition, and non-zero is treated as true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it stops when y is 0, what you have

```
while (y)
```

is short hand for

```
while (y != 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`While`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop) loops loop while a variable is not 0.